# How can I groupby in pandas and then sum values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have the next problem: I have a dataframe in pandas with an attribute 'features' and another attribute 'VOTES'. 'VOTES' is numeric, and 'features' is a string which is repeated in the dataframe. I want to group according to features and sum the values of VOTES, in order to get the next result:

Dataframe initially:

```
+----------+---------+
| features | VOTES   |
+----------+---------+
| A        | 4       |
+----------+---------+
| V        | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| A        | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| C        | 9       |
+----------+---------+
```

I did the following but I got NaN values on VOTES column.

```
dataframe_clusters['VOTES'] = dataframe_clusters.groupby('features')['VOTES'].sum()
```

I want to get the next result:

```
+----------+---------+
| features | VOTES   |
+----------+---------+
| A        | 6       |
+----------+---------+
| V        | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| C        | 9       |
+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
dataframe_clusters.groupby('features').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  features  VOTES
0        A      6
1        C      9
2        V      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=False`, also for not sorting values of `features` is possible add parameter `sort=False`:

```
df = dataframe_clusters.groupby('features', sort=False)['VOTES'].sum().reset_index()

df = dataframe_clusters.groupby('features', as_index=False, sort=False)['VOTES'].sum()
```

---

```
print (df)
  features  VOTES
0        A      6
1        V      3
2        C      9
```

If want assign to new column is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` of aggregated values with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
dataframe_clusters['VOTES'] = dataframe_clusters.groupby('features')['VOTES'].transform('sum')
print (dataframe_clusters)

  features  VOTES
0        A      6
1        V      3
2        A      6
3        C      9
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question is not really clear what you need in the end. The grouping you're doing is OK, but for some reason you're assigning it a column of the same dataFrame. I'm guessing that you need a join in the end. Check this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'features':['A','V','A','C'], 'VOTES':[4,3,2,9]})
totals = df.groupby('features').sum()
print(df)
print(totals)
joined = df.join(totals, on='features', rsuffix='_total')
print(joined)
```

It will give you this:

```
   VOTES features
0      4        A
1      3        V
2      2        A
3      9        C
          VOTES
features       
A             6
C             9
V             3
   VOTES features  VOTES_total
0      4        A            6
1      3        V            3
2      2        A            6
3      9        C            9
```